# Calendar plugin for displaying opening hours for specific days?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, calendar

I need a calendar plugin (preferably for jQuery or even better WordPress) that shows the opening hours when clicking on a date.

The opening hours vary depending on the day of the week and also on the season.

I already took a look at various calendar plugins but most of them are date pickers or oriented to publish events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) will do what you want.

You will need to set a handler on the `dayClick` event ([documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/)).

For example:

```
$("#calDiv").fullCalendar(
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    // change the day's background color just for fun
    $(this).css('background-color', '#6495ED');

    // assuming a call that goes to the server and gets HTML for an opening hours popup
    $.ajax(
         url: '/path/to/get/hours',
         data: {'date' : date}, // pass the date as a param,
         dataType: 'html',
         success: function(data) {
             $("#divForPopup").html(data).show();
         }
    );
}
);
```

Alternatively you could create an event for each day that shows opening hours (or total hours opened, including closing hours).

Comment: Thank you justkt. That is very useful. But ceating an event for each days sounds like a ton of work. Would it be possible to set rules like this: days in august (X opening times), wednesday in august (y opening times)?

Comment: @0al0 - you can do that very easily on the server side (depending on your server-side language) and even in the Javascript - it's all just code.  To understand how fullcalendar handles events, just check out the documentation.